# Any way to initialize multiple views with similar ID names?

Tags: java, android

I am using CheckBoxes and faced similar problem while using TextViews, the following method works correctly but is redundant. I did the same while using TextViews which were 10 in number.

```
 private CheckBox []checkBoxes ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_toast);

        checkBoxes = new CheckBox[5];
        checkBoxes[0] = findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBoxes[1] = findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        checkBoxes[2] = findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        checkBoxes[3] = findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        checkBoxes[4] = findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
    }
```

I have given the id's of the checkboxes a general name, is there any function I can use?
I was thinking if there is someway like following:

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
checkBoxes[i-1]=findViewById(R.id.checkBox(somehow use i));}
```

Or is there any TOTAL DIFFERENT approach I can take?

Comment: what are you trying to acheive here?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way unless using data binding and not doing findViewById

Comment: @HasanBouTaam What I am trying to achieve is that since I assigned IDs of CheckBoxes with are in a patter (checkBox1, checkBox2, etc.) , so can I utilize them through any loop or something else

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by declaring an int array in your resources, with the entries being your CheckBox IDs.

Example:

```
<resources>
<integer-array name="check_box_ids">
    <item>@id/checkBox1</item>
    <item>@id/checkBox2</item>
    <item>@id/checkBox3</item>
    <item>@id/checkBox4</item>
</integer-array>
```

Then, in your `onCreate`, you'll loop through either your local array or the one you created in your resources (`check_box_ids`) - make sure they have both the same size!

```
int[] checkBoxIds = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.check_box_ids);

for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxIds.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i] = findViewById(checkBoxIds[i]);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking if there is someway like following:
``for(int i from 1 to 5){
checkBoxes[i] = findViewById(R.id.checkBox(somehow use the value of i))}``

Comment: That's not possible. The only safe and clean way to achieve something close to what you're describing is the approach I've presented on my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to simplify things:

```
private int[] ids = {R.id.checkBox1,R.id.checkBox2,R.id.checkBox3,R.id.checkBox4,R.id.checkBox5};

private CheckBox []checkBoxes = new CheckBox[5];

//loop 

for(int i =0 ; i<checkBoxes.length ; i++){
checkBoxes[i] = findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

**UPDATE**

**This might be helpful**

Instead of ids, tag your views:

```
<LinearLayout
     id = "@id/layout"
      ........

    <CheckBox
         android:tag = "1"
         ......

    <CheckBox
         android:tag = "2"
         ......

    ........
```

in code:

```
private CheckBox []checkBoxes = new CheckBox[5];
private LinearLayout linearLayout;

//on create

linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

//loop 

for(int i =0 ; i<checkBoxes.length ; i++){
checkBoxes[i] = (CheckBox)linearLayout.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(i+1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's almost the same thing other way round.

Comment: are you looking for something else?

Comment: Added that exact thing in my question.

Comment: What do you mean by somehow use i?

Comment: All I want is someway to utilize the common names of CheckBoxes to initialize them.

Comment: @SatyamBansal check my update it might be what you want.